# LinearLayout.LayoutParams before KitKat

Tags: android

I have the following code snippet:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                            params.setMargins(56, 0, 0, 0);
                            final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                            int pixels = (int) (48 * scale + 0.5f);
                            params.height = pixels;
                            standardTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
                    }
```

I've since found out that LinearLayout.LayoutParams is only available from API 19 (KitKat). Is there a way I can do the above code pre KitKat devices, I've unfortunately not been able to find any alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinearLayout.LayoutParams is added in Api Level 1, see here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html

but you can create your Params with only one new:

```
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

and if you want to apply the height in pixels, just to it immediately:

```
new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, pixels);
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that was the case, but AndroidStudio is throw an error ``Call requires API Level 19 (current min is 14): android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams#LayoutParams`` I have also got an exception on several Android 4.2 and Android 4.3 in my developer console with ``java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>``

Comment: then this is because you are using the new twice and with ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT. Put my code above and your warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

[LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) has been around since API level 1.

You should be able to use it in lower versions without issue as long as your not using any other API's that are not available in previous versions.